# Display PDF file with QWebView

Tags: python, qt, pdf, qt-creator, pyside

I would like to display a window with a QwebView widget in Pyside. For this I use some code generated by QtCreator:

```
#code generated by QtCreator:
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.centralWidget)
        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 380, 270))
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("file:///C:/pdf_folder/test.pdf"))
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

from PySide import QtWebKit

# My code:
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWindow()
    MW.show()

    sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

I am sure to have a pdf file in the specified path, but when I run my script, the pdf file is never displayed in my window.
Do you know what I am doing wrong ?

I saw this topic [Is it possible to get QWebKit to display pdf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607543/is-it-possible-to-get-qwebkit-to-display-pdf-files), but the answer don't work for me (after changing PyQt to Pyside in the import lines).

I also saw this topic [PDF with QWebView: missing refresh/repaint after loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315418/pdf-with-qwebview-missing-refresh-repaint-after-loading), the workaround (using a timer before loading) work for me. however I don't think that using a timer to load a file is a good way to solve the problem.

And, mainly, the code that I used for `Ui_MainWindow` is generated with QtCreator, I didn't change it and I don't want to change it by myself (without using QtCreator). It is just a simple form for a window with only one widget `QtWebKit.QWebView` in which I want to load a file. It should work without weird workaround. Why the code automatically generated don't work ? Am I using QtCreator in a wrong way ?

Comment: see also here [Is it possible to get QWebKit to display pdf files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607543/is-it-possible-to-get-qwebkit-to-display-pdf-files) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315418/pdf-with-qwebview-missing-refresh-repaint-after-loading)

Comment: I agree that my question looked to be the same of this two topics. I edited it to give a better explanation of my problem and explain why it is different. Could you consider it again for the duplicate ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable `QWebView`'s plugins:

```
self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.centralWidget)
self.webView.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
```

also try to set the `QWebView` URL after showing the main window.

```
MW = MainWindow()
MW.show()
MW.ui.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("file:///C:/pdf_folder/test.pdf"))
```

I think the paint events has to do with the fact you don't see the pdf file.

Comment: I tried to add this two lines of code just after `self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.centralWidget)` but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Have you installed some pdf renderer, Acrobat for instance? I think you need to have some installed.

Comment: I tried to set the URL after showing the main window with your code, but I still don't see my pdf file. The only difference that I have with the last change is a sort of quick blink when the window appear, but nothing more.